# RoyalMail Address Validation and AutoComplete APIs

Tags: .net-core, autocomplete, royalmail

I want to integrate **RoyalMail APIs** (in .NetCore API) for validating entered address by the user and AutoComplete API (address suggestions while typing) like Google has? I am not getting any info on their website, wondering if there documents are so bad or I am missing something. Can someone help me in getting there if aware of the APIs?